# json - get results data from JSON api

Tags: php, json, api

I am using a web API to send messages to many people as my application goal. That API works well and the messages are received. The problem is to display the result of messages sent in the application, whether they are sent or no, the receivers, and more. From the API it displays the results using just a single variable like this: `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.displaying results like:

```
Message TestTesting{"response": [{"errors": {"action": "Failed to Send", "error": "No Cost Associated to messages"}}], "success": false}
```

In this way I can't format the results individually, or apply some CSS rules to match with the application. I also can't see the cause of the error that prevented the message to be sent (like low credits balance), so that I won't display it to the user. I want to get individual variables. I tried to search for an answer but the results were that I use JSON decode. I tried it:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json=json_decode($result,true);
print_r($json);
```

It is displaying like:

```
MessageTestingArray ( [response] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [errors] => Array ( [action] => Failed to Send [error] => No Cost Associated to messages ) ) ) [success] => )
```

I tried to use arrays to get them separately using maybe 'action':

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json=json_decode($result,true);
echo $json['action'];
```

But there results were the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\glory\process.php on line 75
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json=json_decode($result,true);

echo $json['response'][0]['errors']['action'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use what @Addil just posted but i personally don't like to hardcode the [0] inside my code. The [0] is there for a reason so that there could be multiple results.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json=json_decode($result,true);
foreach($json['response'] as $response){
echo $response['errors']['action'];
}
```

But keep in mind to do a check before you do a foreach. To see if there is a actual array inside the response with a error array otherwise you will get a error printed out of the foreach.